# Div won't keep height attribute or center

Tags: css, html, margin, centering

I'm working on a project right now and can't get my content area to center. I believe this is due to the main #content div not having a height when inspected in my browsers. I assign the height in my CSS in the #content but this div doesn't seem to keep the assigned attributes.

Here is a snippet of HTML that contains the #content div:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="mainbox">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Vivamus vestibulum nulla nec ante.</li>
            <li>Praesent placerat risus quis eros.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="relatedbox">
        <h1>Related</h1>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the condensed CSS code is:

```
#content {
    height: 500px;
    width: 825px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#content #relatedbox {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 1em 0.5em 1em;
    border: 3px solid #00824c;
    float: left;
}
```

I've tried quite a few things including "position: relative" (and absolute), which looked like the solution to many other similar issues. Doesn't fix mine however. The boxes render right but stick to the left hand side of the div.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or help!

**EDIT (SOLUTION):** I seem to have found a solution, although I'm not sure it is the best. In my HTML I literally just added the styling to the div itself and it picked it up. I can clear all my CSS code in the #content div but I need to keep the #content id because of some other dependencies. Thanks again for every ones help! The code that fixed it:
`<div id="content" style="height: 500px; width: 850px; position: relative; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">`

Comment: your code works as is so we might need to see more of the html. Here is the JSFiddle of your current code with just the content element width decreased so you can see it become centered. http://jsfiddle.net/d2cnR/1/

Comment: @MattMombrea Thanks for the response. In my header div, I'm using a few absolute tags to keep icons in the correct place but other than that I can't think of any other problems that could be causing it.

Comment: It seems to be working. Probably you have overwritten your css style in your page later.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav, I don't think I ever use the height attribute after my call in #content so is it possible some other attribute is changing the height from 500px to 0px? Is there some other way that it could be overwritten?

Comment: So are you getting the height to be 0px?
Try using firebug(firefox) or developer tool(in chrome) chrome to see the actual css values, then you can find whats wrong with your css or html. Also it is possible that some of your later divs or other element is being placed to the right of the #content div. In that case the #content may stick to left side.

Comment: Yeah, in both Chrome and Firefox the #content height is 0. I don't think it could be any of the later divs because only the footer is after the content and I haven't added hardly any code to it. It looks like only the two major boxes are being rendered in the content area so they *aren't* pushing it to the left. At least I don't think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the CSS from the file directly to the div like: `<div id="content" style="height: 500px; width: 850px; position: relative; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to your #content styles.

Comment: Forgot to mention I tried that one, but that doesn't seem to be the issue :/ Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sometimes when I have a div that won't hold its height, I can use `max-height` and `min-height` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using IE, add the below before the `<html>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: I'm not at the moment but I have that that included on all of my HTML files as a good practice! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

if the display is `inline`, I've found it ignores `width`. I changed it to `inline-block` and and it seems to work.